# How Do I list the oauth2 scopes of a service account using the google python sdk?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-workspace

I have a service account with oauth2 scopes assigned to him ([from scopes list](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes?hl=he)) in my Domain Wide Delegation (For example, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.chrome.printers, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.chrome.printers.readonly).

How would I be able to list those scopes using the python sdk / rest api with only the information about the service account (I have a CLIENT ID and the rest of the information about that service acccount)

Comment: You don't have scope on an account but on credentials. Why do you need to know that information?

Comment: I need it for a program I am writing with python sdk in which I need to list the scopes of the account credentials

Comment: That makes no sense!

Comment: why not? There is an option of seeing the scopes in the domain wide delegation part of the google workspace admin, why wouldn't there be some api call for that?